# C++ VISUAL STUDIO

Tags: c++

Se tiene 7 variables del tipo decimal longitudinal, y diferentes entre sí, positivas menores a 10000, encontrar el mayor, menor, quinto menor y tercer mayor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(void)
{

    int n, cont, mayor = 0, menor = 0;

    for (cont = 0; cont <= 6; cont++)
    {
        printf("Ingresa un Numero: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &n);

        if (cont == 0)
        {
            menor = mayor = n;
        }

        if (n < menor && n<10000)
        {
            menor = n;
        }

        if (n > mayor)
        {
            mayor = n;
        }

    }

    printf("El Menor es:  %d ", menor);
    printf("\n");
    printf("El Mayor es:  %d ", mayor);
    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Me quedo la duda de la parte que dice "se tiene 7 variables", ¿querrá decir que es un arreglo de 7 posiciones o 7 variables tal cual?

Comment: son 7 numeros que el usuario tiene que ingresar a la pantalla. en la cual al terminar de colocar los 7 numeros tengo que recibir el mensaje del numero mayor, menor, quinto menor y tercer mayor.

Comment: Ordena las variables y quédate con el primero, el último, el quinto y el tercer número.

Comment: Cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Si el usuario tiene que ingresar los 7 valores, puedes hacer un vector de 7 posiciones, luego ordenarlo y finalmente imprimir lo que te piden con los índices del arreglo, intenta algo así (yo puse los índices del 3er mayor y 5to menor entendiendo que se refiere a orden ascendente y descendente respectivamente, es decir, en ambos casos se refiere al mismo número, si no es asi solo cambia los índices):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  int n[7], i, j;
  i=0;
  j=0;

  int size = sizeof(n) / sizeof(n[0]);

  for(i=0;i<7;i++)
  {
      printf("Escriba el valor %i \n",i+1);
      scanf("%i", &n[i]);
      if(n[i]>10000)
      {
        while(n[i]>10000)
        {
        printf("Debe ingresar un valor positivo menor a 10000 \n");
        printf("Escriba el valor %i \n",i+1);
        scanf("%i", &n[i]);     
      }
      }
  }
  std::sort(n, n + size);

  printf("El mayor es %i\n", n[6]);
  printf("El menor es %i\n", n[0]);
  printf("El 5to menor es %i\n", n[2]);
  printf("El 3er mayor es %i\n", n[2]);

  return 0;
}
```